# eclipse-rcp : how to add double click listener on a ListViewer's item?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a ListViewer in my eclipse-plugin, I want to do some work when user double click on the items in that ListViewer.

I had attached a doubleClick listener with my ListViewer instance, but it will be fired when I  double click on anywhere inside the ListViewer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the current selection inside your listener. Like in the following code:

```
viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();
        if (selection.isEmpty()) return;

        List<Object> list = selection.toList();
        ///...
    }
});
```

Remember that the selection for ListView (and TableViewer, ComboViewer, and TreeViewer) is always a IStructuredSelection..

Comment: but if a item in that list is being selected, then you double click at anywhere inside the ListView,the double click listener will be fired too...

Comment: That is true. To check that you need to use ColumnViewer.getItemAt(Point point) or similar. item.getData() will return the relevant row element... Hope this helps.